# Splitting a hex number

Tags: c

newbie question.

Say for example, I have the hex number 0xABCDEF, how would i split it into 0xAB,0xCD and 0xEF?
Is it like this?

```
unsigned int number = 0xABCDEF
unsigned int ef = a & 0x000011;
unsigned int cd = (a>>8) & 0x000011;
unsigned int ab = (a>>16) & 0x000011;
```

Thanks

Comment: Hex `0x0011` is in binary `0000000000010001`, so that mask will only give you two bits not all eight.

Comment: What is `a`, did you mean `number`?

Answer (score 16):

Use `0xff` as your mask to remove all but 8 bits of a number:

```
unsigned int number = 0xABCDEF
unsigned int ef = number & 0xff;
unsigned int cd = (number>>8) & 0xff;
unsigned int ab = (number>>16) & 0xff;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
unsigned int number = 0xABCDEF
unsigned int ef = number & 0xff;
unsigned int cd = (number >> 8) & 0xff;
unsigned int ab = (number >> 16) & 0xff;
```

Instead of the bitwise and (`&`) operation, you might intead want `ef`, `cd`, `ab` to be `unsigned char` types, depending on the rest of your code and how you're working with these variables. In which case you cast to `unsigned char`:

```
unsigned int number = 0xABCDEF
unsigned char ef = (unsigned char) number;
unsigned char cd = (unsigned char) (number >> 8);
unsigned char ab = (unsigned char) (number >> 16);
```

Answer (score 0):

The mask to use would be `0xFF`, not `0x11`. Apart of this, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

```
void splitByte(unsigned char * split, unsigned int a,int quantBytes)
{
  unsigned char aux;
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<quantBytes;i++)
  {
      split[i]=a&0x00FF; 
      a=(a>>8);
  }
  for(i=0;i<quantBytes-1;i++)
  {
      aux = split[i];
      split[i] = split[quantBytes-i-1];
      split[quantBytes-i-1] = aux;

  }
}
```

In the main:
unsigned char split[4];
splitByte(split, 0xffffffff, 4);